# Delete the data from sql server when after five days

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, triggers

I want to write a trigger or function which runs automatically and delete the data which are 5 days old . I have a data column in the table which stores the current date. The program will run automatically and delete such data. 
I use sql server 2008

Comment: A **trigger** is triggered when a certain event happens - a row is inserted, deleted, updated. A trigger cannot be executed on a regular basis. You need to write a SQL statement (or a stored procedure) that you can schedule from the SQL Server Agent

Answer (score 1):

Better create a job that runs every night to delete the old data.

Trigger is not a good solution for this case, because every `INSERT` or `UPDATE` will invoke the trigger, slowing you down.